# PC Restarts Without Giving Any Warning

Tags: reboot, power

My PC restarts without giving any warning.  I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.  My OS starts well.  After running for some minutes, it restarts.  I couldn't find any reason.

My hardware:

- Processor: `Intel core-i5 2400m 3.2 GHz`
- Motherboard: `Intel DH67CL`
- Graphics Card: `MSI GTX560 2GB DDR5 twin frozr dual oc`
- Power supply: `Thermaltake 650W smart power`
- RAM: `10GB`
- HDD: `Samsung 1TB 7200rpm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At best you have a faulty PSU cable (Kettle Plug) or wall socket.

More likely, you have a faulty PSU (Power Supply), they're practically consumables. The cheaper they are the less efficient and less long they last.
(A 650W PSU is under spec for your rig - it will be at a high load, so it will be running above its ideal temperature range.)

Another possible is a faulty motherboard, which is routing the power. Less likely, but most annoying if it's the case.

You need to get your hardware checked by someone who know's what they are doing basically.

Edit: Overheating possible to, you may have an extremely dusty PC.
You should use canned air or an air hose to clean out your PC, if you have never done this before especially so.
You need to pay attention to the airflow near your computer as well, for example if your computer is in an enclosed space or near a hot object like a TV.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, it turned out to be a problem with the cooling system. Your laptop may be shutting itself down as soon as it detects the CPU reaching critical temperatures to prevent any damage.

Comment: Sounded more like a desktop from his description.

Comment: @Amicable - The comment remains true.  It sounds like his CPU is overheating.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your system is overheating and the sudden restarts without warning is just your pc trying to save itself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a problem of temperature. removes the processor clean this area, new appliance and thermal pulp test your system.

If the problem continues check the power supply, check bios and install updates to news.